# rails deployment in subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

on a dedicated server Debian 7, my default domain is  www.example.org
I installed a mail server as smtp.example.org on localhost, running fine

I would like to deploy a rails app as a subdomain as  : myapp.example.org

I deployed correctly the app, w Capistrano , and added a  vhost :

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
         ServerAdmin webmaster@example.org
         ServerName myapp.example.org
         ServerAlias myapp.example.org
         DocumentRoot /var/www/rails/staging/myapp/current/public
        <Directory /var/www/rails/staging/myapp/current/public>
            AllowOverride All
            Options -MultiViews
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

the I enabled the site and restarted apache and tried to get  http://myapp.example.org
but I always get the default site :  http://www.example.org

my /etc/host is the following :

```
  127.0.0.1       localhost smtp.example.org
  localhost.localdomain localhost smtp
```

when I perform in the console :   apache2ctl -S, I get

```
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
...
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
...
port 80 namevhost myapp.example.org (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/myapp.example.org:1)
```

what did I missed ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer at :

http://shapeshed.com/developing-subdomain-rails-sites-locally/

in the vhost file , I changed  :

```
  ServerAlias *.example.com
  ...
  Options +FollowSymlinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
  RackEnv staging  # or development or production
```